# Reverse relationship lookup in Django REST framework - FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword into field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I know I am not the first one to ask this question but I can't find a solution. I have the following models:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'size'


class Orders(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    brand_id = models.IntegerField()
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shop_id = models.IntegerField()
    item_id = models.IntegerField()
    category_id = models.IntegerField()
    item_gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    return_reason = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'orders'
```

I'm trying to use reverse lookup as it described [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

```
sizes = Size.objects.using('mysql_db').filter(orders__user_id=6)
```

Error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'orders' into field. Choices are: country, id, size
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dictionary/types/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'orders' into field. Choices are: country, id, size
Exception Location: /Users/.../env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in names_to_path, line 1391
Python Executable:  /Users/.../env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.3
```

Comment: Your `filter` statement is correct. I just test it locally with your models and it's working. Your problem should be somewhere else but can't figure right now where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that the query you posted works as is and the problem is elsewhere in your code. Have you run makemigrations and migrate? You can find the working code example [here](https://github.com/arpheno/ReverseForeignKeyFilterExample):

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Size(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'size'


class Orders(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True,primary_key=True)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    brand_id = models.IntegerField()
    user_id = models.IntegerField(default = 6)
    shop_id = models.IntegerField()
    item_id = models.IntegerField()
    category_id = models.IntegerField()
    item_gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    return_reason = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'orders'
```

views.py

```
class ReverseFK(ListView):
    model = Size
    def get_queryset(self):
        Size.objects.create()
        return Size.objects.filter(orders__user_id=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of variants

```
sizes = [item.size for item in Orders.objects.filter(user_id=6)]
```

However, you should use `select_related` to reduce the amount of SQL queries to one.

Otherwise you will implicitly perform n+1 queries.

Comment: I'm not sure if at can be done with `select_related`